# how to make a Node red Custom gauge Animation interacting with sensor data?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, node-red, gauge

I want to make a custom speed gauge with CSS & Javascript to insert in the ui_template node of node red in order to make a custom car interface.
So I've written some basic svg and Css code, I managed to get the gauge to move according to a certain variable value (this variable is going to be the speed sensor value). The probleme is with the animation whenever I change the `pos` variable value the gauge dosen't move from the `pos` current value it resets from the starting position then displays the current `pos`value.
I want it to remember its last position so that when it moves it' start from the that position either increase or decrease to have that perfect node red standard gauge effect.
here is the gauge code:

```js
  var elem = document.getElementById("ss");
  var pos = 30;
  var posup = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (posup == 100 - pos) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } 
    else {
      posup++;
      elem.style.height = posup + "%";
      
    }
  }
```

```css
.ss{
  height: 0%;
}
rect{
  fill: #818181;
}
```

```html
<svg height="300" width="300" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 28.2 62.9" enable-background="new 0 0 28.2 62.9" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#01A9DB" stroke="#818181" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M20.6,57.7l-2.4,2.4C8.5,50.8,2.5,37.8,2.5,23.3C2.5,16,4,9.1,6.8,2.8
 h3.6C7.4,9,5.8,16,5.8,23.3C5.8,36.9,11.5,49.1,20.6,57.7z"/>
  <clippath id="star"><path fill="none" stroke="#070606" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M20.6,57.7l-2.4,2.4C8.5,50.8,2.5,37.8,2.5,23.3C2.5,16,4,9.1,6.8,2.8
 h3.6C7.4,9,5.8,16,5.8,23.3C5.8,36.9,11.5,49.1,20.6,57.7z"/></clippath><g clip-path="url(#star)"><rect  id = "ss" class ="ss" height"" width="100%"></rect></g>
</svg>
```

please try to change the `pos` value withing [0,100] and see the problem with the animation.
I hope that my problem is clear, If there is any solution please tell me and also if there is any other way to make a custom gauge I m open to any suggestion, thank you :)

Comment: what about adding `transition:1s;` to .ss ?

Comment: I m not using any Css animation so the transistion wouldn't do anything in this situation.

Comment: transtion and animation are completely different.. transition are useful when you are updating some value to have a smooth change

Comment: Thank you very I tried using a transition and it worked perfectly well thanks a lot :)